# Invalid output structure error while using running Data Transformation for AWS Kinesis Firehose

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to use AWS Firehose to send the data to S3 through my spring application using the PUT Apis. But the data is in AVRO. So I wrote a lambda function for Data Transformation to transform the data to JSON format.

**Lambda function:** https://github.com/GurucharanSharma/avro-convertor-lambda.

> *NOTE: In case someone wants to run the lambda function - you need not package/install the code. Just get the jar file from `target` folder in the repository and upload
> to AWS Lambda. Runtime is Java 17 and handler is
> `com.paytmlabs.adtech.Handler::handleRequest`*

**Here is the sample test event:**

```
{
  "invocationId": "invocationIdExample",
  "deliveryStreamArn": "arn:aws:kinesis:EXAMPLE",
  "region": "ca-central-1",
  "records": [
    {
      "recordId": "49546986683135544286507457936321625675700192471156785154",
      "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1495072949453,
      "data": "AFRSRVFJRC0yZjU3NzQ2Zi0zMTZlLTRlZjgtYThhOS0xNTIwZjVjYzlkZDUcMjAwMTM0MjUxMjI4NzIGVVBJDjExNjQ5NTACAgIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIcTU9BX0NPTlRFWFRVQUwACBg5ODcxNzY4Njg3ODMUMTIzNDU2NzgxMRgwODk4MTAyNzQwODcUMTIzNDU5MjIzMAAEAgICAgAAAAAAAAACAACsAUF1ZGllbmNlIHNlcnZpY2UgZmFpbGVkIHRvIHJlc3BvbmQgZm9yIGdldCBhc3NvY2lhdGVkIGFkc2V0cywgYWZ0ZXIgbWF4IGF0dGVtcHRzIG9mOiAxvuKHqbxiAA=="
    }
  ]
}
```

**Final output from lambda:**

```
{
    "records": [{
        "recordId": "49643047012485051063095397118562844340986462806099361794000000",
        "result": "Ok",
        "data": "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"
    }, {
        "recordId": "49643047012485051063095397119602520545855043965066149890000000",
        "result": "Ok",
        "data": "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"
    }, {
        "recordId": "49643047012485051063095397120278310079019621742446379010000000",
        "result": "Ok",
        "data": "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"
    }]
}
```

Everything seems to work fine till here, but firehose is giving the following error:

```
{
  "attemptsMade": 4,
  "arrivalTimestamp": 1691724750657,
  "errorCode": "Lambda.FunctionError",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid output structure. Check your function and make sure the output is in required format. In addition to that, make sure the processed records contain valid result status of Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed.",
  "attemptEndingTimestamp": 1691724828300,
  "rawData": "AFRSRVFJRC0yNjA5NWNhMy01YTFhLTRmYWItODM1My0yYzk1OWE5YmQ5MTIcMjAwMTM0MjUxMjI4NzIGVVBJDjExNjQ5NTACAgIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIcTU9BX0NPTlRFWFRVQUwACBg5ODcxNzY4Njg3ODMYMDg5ODEwMjc0MDg3FDEyMzQ1Njc4MTEUMTIzNDU5MjIzMAAEAgICAgAAAAAAAAACAACsAUF1ZGllbmNlIHNlcnZpY2UgZmFpbGVkIHRvIHJlc3BvbmQgZm9yIGdldCBhc3NvY2lhdGVkIGFkc2V0cywgYWZ0ZXIgbWF4IGF0dGVtcHRzIG9mOiAxzPW4qrxiAA==",
  "lambdaArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:272415727726:function:DecisionEngineAvroConverter:$LATEST"
}
```

Can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here. Any suggestions?